# How to display html content in notification message (success for example)

Tags: magento-1.9

I am trying to put html content in a success message when the account is updated such as:

```
            $successMsg = '<p>Your request to change your data has been registered.</p>
<p>For further questions, please feel free to <a href="/contacts">contact us</a></p>';
$session->addSuccess($successMsg);
```

The problem is that the html is not interpreted. I have tried to encode the html characters but without success.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14213691/using-html-within-the-addsuccess-method

"Flag Mage_Core_Block_Messages::$_escapeMessageFlag defines if to use htmlEscape() method with the message text, so you can set up your rule for the selected path.

```
Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlock('messages')->setEscapeMessageFlag(false);
```

"